# Finding a theoretical explanation for a simulated probability distribution of a casino game

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, game-theory

I am developing a casino game for a statistics project. The rules are as follows:

> This game costs \$1 to play. The player rolls a six sided die. If the rolled face is odd, the player loses and is given \$0. If the face is even, they earn a prize of \$1. The player is given the option to accept their payout or keep playing after each successful roll. If they choose to roll again, they will earn an additional dollar for each successful even roll. If they ever roll an odd, they will lose all earnings and receive \$0. The player continues until they lose by rolling an odd number or until they have rolled 5 times (\$5 maximum payout).

I was unable to determine the probability distribution for each payout theoretically, so I instead simulated them using Python (note: I am a novice programmer). My simulation assumes a 50% probability of quitting after each successful roll.

```
import random

total_winnings = 0
payoutFrequency = {0: 0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0}

# Let zero be odd and 1 be even
chooseList = [0, 1]

def play_game():
    winnings = 0
    roll = 0
    while roll < 5:
        choice = random.choice(chooseList)
        if choice == 1:
            winnings += 1
            # Simulate choosing to quit
            # Assume 50% chance of quitting after each win
            quitDecision = random.choice(chooseList)
            if quitDecision == 1:
                break
        else:
            winnings = 0
            break
        roll += 1
    return winnings

simulations = 10000000
for i in range(simulations):
    payout = play_game()
    total_winnings += payout
    payoutFrequency[payout] += 1
    
print(f"Expected Winnings: {total_winnings/simulations}")
print(f"""Probability Distributions of Payouts:\n
        $0: {payoutFrequency[0]/simulations}\n
    $1: {payoutFrequency[1]/simulations}\n
        $2: {payoutFrequency[2]/simulations}\n
    $3: {payoutFrequency[3]/simulations}\n
        $4: {payoutFrequency[4]/simulations}\n
    $5: {payoutFrequency[5]/simulations}""")
```

Running the simulation 10,000,000 times returned the following results:

```
Expected Winnings: 0.4471606
Probability Distributions of Payouts:

        $0: 0.6660241

        $1: 0.2500339

        $2: 0.0624574

        $3: 0.0156626

        $4: 0.0038859

        $5: 0.0019361>
```

These coordinate to probabilities (I assume) are 2/3, 1/4, 1/16, 1/64, 1/256, and 1/512, respectively. Does anyone have an idea or explanation on how to achieve these numbers theoretically?

Edit: This game is purposefully meant to make a profit for the casino. The expected value should be negative after the buy-in is subtracted. Ideally, this game would have the allure of logic and control so that players will be enticed to play.

Comment: Why use a die?  Isn't it simpler to just flip a coin...same distribution of outcomes...or have I misunderstood the rules?  In any case, there are only finitely many paths, backwards induction should determine the optimal strategy.

Comment: Your probabilities do not add up to $1$; they would if the probability of $0$ was $\frac{341}{512}=0.666015625$

Comment: Not sure the game is worth playing, by the way.  Just looking at the first two rounds...If I have understood the rules, you have a $\frac 14$ chance of winning $\$2$ and a $\frac 34$ chance of going bust, making the expected value very negative.  So stopping at the second win can't be optimal...but the expected value of the three round version is also negative.

Comment: @lulu - the odds in the first round are fair, but not in the later rounds. So, since the player is given an option, playing only $0$ or $1$ rounds maximises the expected net profit, and then it is $0$.

Comment: @Henry  I must be misreading.  The way I read it, you pay $\$1$ to play, and after the first round you might get $\$1$ back...making the expected return a loss of fifty cents.    Do you imagine that the player gets the buy in returned if they win the first round?  Is it paid in again for any subsequent rounds?

Comment: As I see it, and again I may well be misunderstanding the rules.  The only possible strategies are to play to the $n^{th}$ round and stop (either broke or with a pay out of $\$n$).  For each possible $n$, the winning payout has probability $2^{-n}$, and it is easy to see that the expected value is negative for all $n$.  Of course, it is different if your bet is returned at some point, but the idea shouldn't change...just redo the computation accordingly.

Comment: @lulu I decided to use a die instead of a coin because it fits better with the casino theme. Practically, they have the same probability of winning: 50%

Comment: @lulu - you seem to be correct.  If there was no cost of playing, the best strategy might be to aim to win once or twice, in either case with an expected gain of $\frac12 \times 1$ or $\frac14 \times 2=\frac12$, so the cost of playing should be no more than $\frac12$ to be fair.

Comment: @JaxsonLiening  Please edit your post for clarity.  As it stands, the rules are simply not clear.  Nor is your simulation.  What strategy are you simulating?  How did you decide that this strategy was optimal?  What does "optimal" mean here anyway?

Comment: @lulu I am not trying to find an optimal strategy. I am just trying to find an explanation for the probability distribution of simulated payouts. A player wins \$1 for each even roll and the game costs \$1 to play. Rolling a single even gets your money back. Rolling two consecutive evens earns \$2, etc. I might decrease the price to \$0.50 to make it more fair.

Comment: But the player has an option to stop.  You need to specify the circumstances under which the player exercises that option.  It makes no sense to speak of simulated payouts unless the strategy is specified.  If, say, your strategy is to keep on playing no matter what, then the only possible payouts are $0$ and $5$, right?  There is no way to earn exactly $3$ via this particular strategy, for example.

Comment: For my simulation I assumed that there is a 50% chance of quitting after each successful roll. This was a made-up number to average the chances of a player stopping or quitting. I figured addicted gambles would be overconfident and eventually lose money.

Comment: I suggest editing your post to reflect this strategy, it's not apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use $H$ to mean "heads", $T$ to mean "tails", $P$ to mean "play again", and $Q$ to mean quit. For example, when I write
$$
HPHPHQ,
$$
what I mean is the series of events where the first flip is heads, then the player chooses to play again, then the second flip is heads, then the player chooses to play again, then the third flip is heads, after which the player quits. For the situation above, the player receives a payout \$3.

To compute the probabilities you want, we just need to enumerate all of the possible ways each payout can happen, and add up the probabilities of each way.

1. The only way to get a payout of \$1 is the sequence $HQ$ (you must win the first flip, then quit immediately). The probability of this is $(1/2)\times (1/2)=(1/2)^2=25\%$, because there is a $1/2$ chance you flip $H$, and then a $1/2$ chance the player quits.
2. The only way to get a payout of \$2 is the sequence $HPHQ$, which has a probability of $(1/2)^4=1/16=6.25\%$.
3. The only way to get a payout of \$3 is the sequence $HPHPHQ$, which has a probability of $(1/2)^6=1.5625\%$.
4. The only way to get a payout of \$4 is the sequence $HPHPHPHQ$, which has a probability of $(1/2)^8\approx 0.39\%$.
5. The only way to get a payout of \$5 is the sequence $HPHPHPHPH$, which has a probability of $(1/2)^9\approx 0.195\%$.
6. There are lots of ways to get a payout of \$0. These include $T$, $HPT$, $HPHPT$, $HPHPHPT$, and $HPHPHPHPT$. Adding up the probabilities of each of these, we get
   $$
   \frac12+\frac18+\frac1{32}+\frac1{128}+\frac1{512}=\frac{341}{512}= 66.6015625\%
   $$Note that this is NOT equal to $2/3$, though it is pretty close.

Comment: The sum converges to 2/3 if you can play 6, 7, 8, … times.